# Java:inetaddress to String conversion

Tags: java

I have searched a lot but i could not find any way to convert inetaddress type to string(may be my searching is not that good :S).I have to convert it into string type because i have to display the result in textarea(gui component) which requires string type.So can anyone how is this possible??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Java API for InetAddress class has good methods for your needs, I see.
Try these methods. You can check out other property getters of InetAddress for your further requirements.

```
public static void main ( String [] args ) throws UnknownHostException
{
    // Instantiate your own InetAddress object.
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
    String hostIP = address.getHostAddress() ;
    String hostName = address.getHostName();
    System.out.println( "IP: " + hostIP + "\n" + "Name: " + hostName);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried to [InetAddress.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#toString%28%29) method?

Comment: This returns a forward slash.  Use getHostAddress() instead.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947435/inetaddress-tostring-returns-a-forward-slash

Comment: this will return hostname/ipaddress.

Answer (score 3):

Just call the InetAddress toString() method. Also, if you specifically want the host name, use getHostName. If you want a string representation of the IP address, use **getHostAddress()**.

sample :

```
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName("193.125.22.1");
System.out.println(inet.toString());
```

for more information see: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.net/InetAddressgetByNameStringname.htm

Comment: upvoted for the important bit : getHostAddress if you just want the address string

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
System.out.println(Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
```

?