# InetAddress.toString() returns a forward slash

Tags: java

I have a variable packet of type `DatagramPacket`. While `packet.getAddress().toString()` results in a String representing an the IP address, it has an extra `/` appended to the beginning of the String:

```
/127.0.0.1
```

I can easily remove the leading `'/'`, but is there a better way to just obtain a string representation of the IP? I am worried because what if there are more `'/'` in other situations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the following:

```
packet.getAddress().getHostAddress()
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29):

> Returns the IP address string in textual presentation.

Contrast that with [`InetAddress.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#toString%28%29):

> Converts this IP address to a `String`. The string returned is of the form: hostname / literal IP address. If the host name is unresolved, no reverse name service lookup is performed. The hostname part will be represented by an empty string.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want the IP, use the host address:

```
String address = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").getHostAddress();
```

If you just want the host name, use

```
String hostname = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").getHostName();
```

The slash you're seeing is probably when you do an implicit toString() on the returned InetAddress as you try to print it out, which prints the host name and address delimited by a slash (e.g. stackoverflow.com/64.34.119.12). You could use

```
String address = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").toString().split("/")[1];
String hostname = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").toString().split("/")[0];
```

But there is no reason at all to go to a String intermediary here. InetAddress keeps the two fields separate intrinsically.

Comment: copied from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361802/slash-before-inetaddress-getbynamehost